# How to create a Quaternion rotation from a forward- and up- vector?

Tags: vectors, 3d, rotations, quaternions, programming

I need the rotation Quaternion of an object, I have it's foward and up directions (as 3D vectors), so I thought it would be easy to create a Quaternion rotation from that, but I can't seem to get it right.

I'm sure there are multiple ways to do this. (with or without matrices for example) I just need one that always works.

I'm working in C++, directx, so I have the DirectXMath libraries available to use.

Edit:

Turns out there's an easy way to do this with the directx, as there is a function that creates the TransformationMatrix from forward and upvector.

I'm leaving this open, as I'm still interested in knowing how to do this manually. (withouth directx)

Comment: What are forward and up directions?

Comment: If the object has no rotation, it's forward direction would be (0,0,1), and it's up direction would be (0,1,0), because the Y-axis is the global Up-axis, and the Z-axis is the global Forward-axis. At least in my case. I don't really know how to explain it better, it's a 3d programming thing I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You calculate “direction-left” vector as $v_{\mathrm{l}}=v_{\mathrm{u}}\times v_{\mathrm{f}}$. Then by writing your vectors as three columns with the order forward—left—up, you obtain a rotation matrix $M$. Finally:
$$
q_0= \frac12\sqrt{1 + \mathrm{Tr}\ M},\\
q_1 = \frac{M_{32} - M_{23}}{4q_0},\qquad
q_2 = \frac{M_{13} - M_{31}}{4q_0},\qquad
q_3 = \frac{M_{21} - M_{12}}{4q_0}
$$

Comment: I tried that before, but it didn't work. Could be that I made a mistake in my code and somehow used the matrix wrong though.
thanks for your answer.